# All the rqt commands are not responding and some error is being shown. please help

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All the rqt commands are not responding and some error is being shown:

```
riddhi@riddhi-Inspiron-N5010:~$ rosrun rqt_console rqt_console
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/rqt_console/rqt_console", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main.main(sys.argv, standalone='rqt_console.console.Console'))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/main.py", line 59, in main
    return super(Main, self).main(argv, standalone=standalone, plugin_argument_provider=plugin_argument_provider, plugin_manager_settings_prefix=str(hash(os.environ['ROS_PACKAGE_PATH'])))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/main.py", line 336, in main
    from python_qt_binding import QT_BINDING
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .binding_helper import loadUi, QT_BINDING, QT_BINDING_MODULES, QT_BINDING_VERSION  # @UnusedImport
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 252, in <module>
    getattr(sys, 'SELECT_QT_BINDING_ORDER', None),
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 98, in _select_qt_binding
    raise ImportError("Could not find Qt binding (looked for: %s):\n%s" % (', '.join(["'%s'" % b for b in binding_order]), '\n'.join(error_msgs)))
ImportError: Could not find Qt binding (looked for: 'pyqt', 'pyside'):
  ImportError for 'pyqt': No module named PyQt5.QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 89, in _select_qt_binding
    QT_BINDING_VERSION = binding_loader(required_modules, optional_modules)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 131, in _load_pyqt
    _named_import('PyQt5.%s' % module_name)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 111, in _named_import
    module = builtins.__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named PyQt5.QtCore

  ImportError for 'pyside': No module named PySide2.QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 89, in _select_qt_binding
    QT_BINDING_VERSION = binding_loader(required_modules, optional_modules)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 163, in _load_pyside
    _named_import('PySide2.%s' % module_name)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 111, in _named_import
    module = builtins.__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named PySide2.QtCore
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264034/all-the-rqt-commands-are-not-responding-and-some-error-is-being-shown.-please-help/) by [rid7](https://answers.ros.org/users/30774/rid7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-06-16**:
It looks like you don't have PyQt5 installed. If you provide some details about what your operating system is, which version of ROS you're using and how you installed ROS, someone can probably provide appropriate instructions for installing it.

**Comment by [rid7](https://answers.ros.org/users/30774/rid7/) on 2017-06-19**:
I have installed the Kinetic Kame version of ROS in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and i installed ROS according to the instructions in the tutorials.

**Comment by [tobidelbruck](https://answers.ros.org/users/39773/tobidelbruck/) on 2019-02-01**:
Another newbie here. I just installed ros melodic following installation instructions on virgin ubuntu 18.04 LTS system. Only previous stuff that might be related is installation of CUDA and cuDNN.
I get the same error when trying to view a rosbag with rqt_bag. No space here to show results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you installed from apt by following http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu , then the QT5 python modules should have been installed automatically.

You can try to reinstall the python qt5 packages manually by running:

```
sudo apt-get install libpyside2-dev libshiboken2-dev pyqt5-dev python-pyqt5 python-pyqt5.qtsvg python-pyside2 python-sip-dev shiboken2
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rid7](https://answers.ros.org/users/30774/rid7/) on 2017-06-20**:
Thanx a lot. It solved the problem